# Wordpress next/previous post link

Tags: custom-post-types

I need help, please. I'm a newbie on Wordpress.

This code is working:

```
$previous_post_url = get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false, '', false));
$next_post_url = get_permalink(get_adjacent_post(false, '', true));

<a href="{{ $previous_post_url }}" class="nav-arrow prev"></a>
<a href="{{ $next_post_url }}" class="nav-arrow next"></a>
```

Not until, we install WPML.

I'm trying to change it by the following code, but the "get_next_post()" is somewhat not displaying anything. :|

```
@if ( $prev_post = get_previous_post() )
    <a href="{!! get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ) !!}" class="nav-arrow prev"></a>
@endif
@if ( $next_post = get_next_post() )
    <a href="{!! get_permalink( $next_post->ID ) !!}" class="nav-arrow next"></a>
@endif
```